# using the camera and saving images to firebase does not work

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, base64, uri

I want to take picture with camera and then want to upload that picture (taken with camera) to firebase storage. I have studied many questions related to this but that does not make any sense to me. Here is my code.

```
package com.ivtech.shah.yunas.fireapp;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

public class ActivityCamera extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE=1;

private static final  int GALLERY_REQUEST = 2;
Bitmap imageBitmap = null;
private ImageButton takepic;
private EditText mDescription;
private Button mSavebtn;
private ProgressDialog mProgress;
private StorageReference mStorage;
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
private Uri imageUri=null;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
    takepic= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imagebtntotakepic);
    mDescription = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextCameraDesc);
    mSavebtn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnstartsaving);
      mProgress= new ProgressDialog(this);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mStorage= FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("UsersData");



    takepic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {



        }
    });
    mSavebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startSaving();
        }
    });



}
// Save button funtion
private void startSaving() {
    mProgress.setMessage("Uploading Your Data..");

    final String descrition_txt =mDescription.getText().toString().trim();
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(descrition_txt) && imageBitmap!=null){
        mProgress.show();
        StorageReference filepath= mStorage.child("Saved_Images").child(imageUri.getLastPathSegment());
        filepath.putFile(imageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
             Toast.makeText(ActivityCamera.this,"Uploading Finished!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }) ;
        mProgress.dismiss();


    }
}
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    if (imageBitmap==null ) {
        Intent intent= new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent,CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    super.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode==CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode==RESULT_OK){
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        takepic.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
// Actually this uri is null, im confuse in this

       Uri imageuri= data.getData();
       takepic.setImageURI(imageuri);


        StorageReference filepath= mStorage.child("Saved_Images").child(imageUri.getLastPathSegment());
        filepath.putFile(imageuri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                String user_id = mAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

                Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                //DatabaseReference newPost = mDatabase.child(user_id).push();
                DatabaseReference newPost = mDatabase.push();
                // newPost.child("title").setValue(title_txt);

                newPost.child("image").setValue(downloadUrl.toString());


                Toast.makeText(ActivityCamera.this, "worked ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        }}
}
```

I heard that I need to convert uri to base64 but I can not do that any suggestion or what I changes do I need to make in this code.

Comment: that does not make any sense sir

Comment: I'm not sure what sense you are looking for.

Comment: See this code from [our talk at I/O last year](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xAsvwy1-oxE): https://gist.github.com/puf/f49a1b07e92952b44f2dc36d9af04e3c#file-mainactivity-java-L162

Answer (score 0):

if you want to capture image and upload that picture to firebase, then i hope this code will be help you.

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_photo);
    intent = getIntent();
    user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    getUserToken();

    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myDBRef = database.getReference("profile");
    mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("profile_photo").child(userUid);
    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    selectedIV = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.selected_imageView);
    uploadButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.upload_button);
    uploadButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    fromCamera = (Button)findViewById(R.id.from_camera_button);
    fromCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try {
                // use standard intent to capture an image
                Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/perfectDatingProfile");
                if (!direct.exists()) {
                    File wallpaperDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/perfectDatingProfile");
                    wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
                }
                destination = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/perfectDatingProfile", "cropped.png"));
                captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, destination);

                startActivityForResult(captureIntent, 1);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
            }
        }
    });
    laterButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.later_button);
    uploadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            uploadPicture();
        }
    });
    myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    selectImageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.select_photo_button);

    laterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String userName = intent.getExtras().getString("userName");
            String sex = intent.getExtras().getString("sex");
            String uid = intent.getExtras().getString("uid");
            Integer year = intent.getExtras().getInt("year");
            Integer month = intent.getExtras().getInt("month");
            Integer dayOfMonth = intent.getExtras().getInt("dayOfMonth");
            Double latitude = intent.getExtras().getDouble("latitude");
            Double longitude = intent.getExtras().getDouble("longitude");
            userObj = new ProfileModel(userName,sex,uid,year,month,dayOfMonth,latitude,longitude,"none", "none");
            myRef.child("profile").child(userObj.getUid()).setValue(userObj);
            startActivity(new Intent(PhotoActivity.this,BaseActivity.class));
        }
    });
    if(intent.getExtras() == null){
        laterButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    selectImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cropIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            cropIntent.putExtra("crop","true");
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX",1);
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY",1);
            cropIntent.putExtra("return-data",false);
            Log.d("------",Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
            File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/perfectDatingProfile");
            if (!direct.exists()) {
                File wallpaperDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/perfectDatingProfile");
                wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
            }
            destination = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/perfectDatingProfile", "cropped.png"));
            cropIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, destination);
            startActivityForResult(cropIntent, 2);
        }
    });
    ProfileModel sharedModel = getPreferences();
    if (sharedModel !=null){
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/perfectDatingProfile/profile.jpg");
        selectedIV.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

After that you can store your image in your sd card :

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == GALLEY_INTENT && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        selectedIV.setImageURI(destination);
        imageFile = new File(destination.getPath());
        uploadButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        toastFilesize();
        Bitmap bigProfile = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(destination.getPath());
        smallProfile = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bigProfile,250,250,false);
        bitmapToFile(smallProfile,"smallProfile");
    }else if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        selectedIV.setImageURI(destination);
        imageFile = new File(destination.getPath());
        uploadButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        toastFilesize();
        Bitmap bigProfile = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(destination.getPath());
        smallProfile = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bigProfile,250,250,false);
        bitmapToFile(smallProfile,"smallProfile");
    }
}

private void toastFilesize(){
    Cursor returnCursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    int nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
    int sizeIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE);
    returnCursor.moveToFirst();
    Toast.makeText(PhotoActivity.this,Long.toString(returnCursor.getLong(sizeIndex)),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
private void bitmapToFile(Bitmap bitmap, String name) {
    smallImageFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/perfectDatingProfile", "small.jpg");

    OutputStream os;
    try {
        os = new FileOutputStream(smallImageFile);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, os);
        os.flush();
        os.close();
        Log.d("------",imageFile.getAbsolutePath().toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error writing bitmap", e);
    }
}
```

now you can store your image on firebase using uploadfpicture();

```
  private void uploadPicture(){

    StorageReference filepath = mStorage.child("profile");

    mProgressDialog.setMessage("Uploading.....");
    mProgressDialog.show();

    filepath.child("small").putFile(Uri.fromFile(smallImageFile)).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            Uri downloadUri = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
            Log.d("2112","success upload small file" + userUid);
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(PhotoActivity.this,"Upload Failed..",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    filepath.putFile(Uri.fromFile(imageFile)).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            downloadUri = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
            storeToLocal();

        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(PhotoActivity.this,"Upload Failed..",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}

private void getUserToken(){
    if (user != null) {
        userUid = user.getUid();

    }
}

private void storeToLocal(){
    islandRef = mStorage.child("profile");
    try {
        localFile = File.createTempFile("images", "jpg");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    islandRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
            downloadUri = uri;
            islandRef.child("small").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                    smallUri = uri;
                    uploadUserObj();
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {

                }
            });

        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {

        }
    });
}

private ProfileModel getPreferences(){
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = preferences.getString("myProfile", "");
    ProfileModel obj = gson.fromJson(json, ProfileModel.class);

    return obj;
}
private void uploadUserObj(){
    if(intent.getExtras() == null){
        ProfileModel sharedModel = getPreferences();
        sharedModel.setPhotoUrl(downloadUri.toString());
        sharedModel.setSmallProfileUri(smallUri.toString());
        myRef.child("profile").child(sharedModel.getUid()).setValue(sharedModel);

        Log.d("------","from other activity");

    }else {
        Log.d("------","from profile activity");
        String userName = intent.getExtras().getString("userName");
        String sex = intent.getExtras().getString("sex");
        String uid = intent.getExtras().getString("uid");
        Integer year = intent.getExtras().getInt("year");
        Integer month = intent.getExtras().getInt("month");
        Integer dayOfMonth = intent.getExtras().getInt("dayOfMonth");
        Double latitude = intent.getExtras().getDouble("latitude");
        Double longitude = intent.getExtras().getDouble("longitude");

        userObj = new ProfileModel(userName,sex,uid,year,month,dayOfMonth,latitude,longitude,downloadUri.toString(), smallUri.toString());
        myRef.child("profile").child(userObj.getUid()).setValue(userObj);
    }

    islandRef.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            bitmapServer = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(localFile.getAbsolutePath());
            createDirectoryAndSaveFile(bitmapServer,"profile.jpg");
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();

        }
    });
}

private void createDirectoryAndSaveFile(Bitmap imageToSave, String fileName) {
    File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/perfectDatingProfile");

    if (!direct.exists()) {

        File wallpaperDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/perfectDatingProfile");
        wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
    }

    File file = new File(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/perfectDatingProfile"), fileName);
    if (file.exists()) {
        file.delete();
    }
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        imageToSave.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

        startActivity(new Intent(PhotoActivity.this,BaseActivity.class));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String imageUrl) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is a large code i can find in it what im looking for

Comment: you can capture image and store on firebase using this code. but if you only want to upload captured image then you can use uploadUserObj() function and uploadPicture();